# How to limit number of returns from IMAP with Java Mail?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imap

Is there a way to just retrieve last 10 emails from IMAP and message count for all unread mails. I am creating an app which sends notification when user receives new mail and this code works but when user has too many unread mails app can crash because this code firstly loads all unread emails.

```
fun getUnreadMails(): Array<Message> {

    val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())
    val store = session.getStore("imaps")
    store.connect(
        "mail.metropolitan.ac.rs",
        993,
        email,
        password
    )
    val inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX")
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)


    val messages = inbox.search(
        FlagTerm(Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false)
    )

    Arrays.sort(
        messages
    ) { m1: Message, m2: Message ->
        try {
            return@sort m2.sentDate.compareTo(m1.sentDate)
        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    for (message: Message in messages)
    {
        println("Message:  " + message.subject)
    }

    return messages;
}
```

Comment: Sure, that's possible. You can change the call to inbox.search to limit the set of messages search (e.g. "search for the unseen ones among the last 100 messages" or "search for the unseen ones among the messages from last week") or you can take a ten-item slice of the messages array if inbox.search returns more than ten. Each of these changes should add 1-2 lines of code. 2-4 lines if you want to combine them.

Comment: Is inbox.search performed on client or server?

Comment: What flag should i use to fetch last 10  emails?

Comment: inbox.search is performed on the server. If you want to the last ten messages, you don't need a search at all. Open the mailbox and call [getMessageCount()](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getMessageCount--), then call [getMessage()](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getMessage-int-) ten times. If gMC() returns 1004, you want gM(995), gM(996), 996 etc.